# formatting issues with multiple csv.writers

Tags: python, csv, filtering

I am trying to filter an input file and write the filtered lines to a 'filtered' file and the non-filtered lines to a 'saved' file, but I can't seem to solve my formatting issues

after creating a set of filters...

```
with inFile:
    file_reader = csv.reader(inFile, delimiter='\t')
    filtered_name = inFile.name + '_filtered.txt'
    filtered_writer = csv.writer(open(filtered_name,'wb'), delimiter='\t')
    saved_name = inFile.name + '_saved.txt'
    saved_writer = csv.writer(open(saved_name, 'wb'), delimiter='\t')
    for data in file_reader:
        if (data[1], data[2]) in filters:
            filtered_writer.writerows(data)
        else:
            saved_writer.writerows(data)
```

The filtering step is working properly and my output looks fine if I only write to a single output file. In general, the output files should look like:

```
ABC 12345  6789   
DEF 12346  6790
```

But instead they look like:

```
A  B  C
1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  9
D  E  F
1  2  3  4  6
6  7  9  0
```

What am I doing wrong?

edit: I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: Oh my. It should be 'writerow' rather than 'writerows'... happy Monday everybody! Time for my coffee...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want to use `writerow` (not plural) as you are only outputting one row at a time, correct?

`writerows` is interpreting `data` as a list of lists (which it is) but it's actually a list of strings (a string can be interpreted as a list of characters). And so it's splitting each string into a list of characters and outputting one character per column.

Comment: Thanks, see above. Time for a coffee and a walk of shame.